# Is there a way to test if a browser supports flash/silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, flash, ajax, silverlight

I'm trying to determine if a browser that my content is being pushed to supports flash/silverlight. That way, if there is no support on the browser, I can interchange the flash/silverlight components with HTML/AJAX components.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to depend upon exactly what you're doing. Whatever method you're using to embed the Flash or Silverlight probably already provides a way to do this. For example, here's an article on [how SWFObject handles this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/alternative_content.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [jQuery browser plugin detection](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqplugin) plugin.